# VBA code to click on next page in website using Firefox Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to click on 2nd and 3rd page in webpage using Firefox Selenium below is the html code.
Please help!!

```html
<ul>
<li ng-class="{disabled:pagerObj.currentPage === 1}" ng-click="setPage(pagerObj.currentPage - 1);" class="disabled">Previous</li>
<li ng-class="{active:pagerObj.currentPage === page}" ng-repeat="page in pagerObj.pages track by $index" ng-click="setPage(page, $event);" class="ng-binding ng-scope active">1</li>
<li ng-class="{active:pagerObj.currentPage === page}" ng-repeat="page in pagerObj.pages track by $index" ng-click="setPage(page, $event);" class="ng-binding ng-scope">2</li>
<li ng-class="{active:pagerObj.currentPage === page}" ng-repeat="page in pagerObj.pages track by $index" ng-click="setPage(page, $event);" class="ng-binding ng-scope">3</li>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far and tell us where you have problems grasping the error.

Comment: you try with the xpath //ul/li[2] or //ul/li[3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpaths for

Link 1

```
//li[contains(@class,'ng-binding ng-scope')][contains(text(),'1')]

//ul//li[contains(text(),'1')]
```

Link2

```
//li[contains(@class,'ng-binding ng-scope')][contains(text(),'2')]

//ul//li[contains(text(),'2')]
```

Link3

```
//li[contains(@class,'ng-binding ng-scope')][contains(text(),'3')]

//ul//li[contains(text(),'3')]
```

Comment: @anupam try with xpaths

Comment: Hi all thanks for reply,@ iamsankalp89 your code is working fine-driver.FindElementByXPath("//li[contains(@class,'ng-binding ng-scope')][contains(text(),'2')]").Click

Comment: Glad , Please accept as answer on ticking on right icon

Comment: Hi  iamsankalp89, Please help me how to tick on right icon